# Let's add an earth science related feed in our chat room

Tags: feature-request, chat

I've noticed that the Academia chat room has a feed for related questions on other sites. Go there and have a look to see how it works.

How about we add one for ourselves? I think we can use geochemistry from Chemistry, or maybe earth from Astronomy.

Here are the instructions on how to do it:

[How can I configure the feed reader in my chat room?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67700/how-can-i-configure-the-feed-reader-in-my-chat-room)

Only a mod or that chat owner can do it as it seems, and I am neither.

Comment: I can add feeds.  Which sites do you want?

Comment: I think the ones listed in the question would work, @casey. Maybe also [earth on Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/earth).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I added three feeds to the ticker in our chatroom (earth on astronomy and physics, geochemistry on chemistry) so any new questions posted to those tags on those sites will show up in the ticker where questions posted to our site currently show up.

If you want that tweaked in any way (e.g. if you would rather have a dedicated room they get posted as chat messages), or more added, just ping me (or any other mod) and we can adjust the room.

Comment: There is also [History of Science and Mathematics StackExchange](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/earth-sciences), though the tag is not really active.

Comment: earth-like in worldbuilding is active and relevant

Comment: I don't think it's working. Nothing shows up in our chat room.